# responsive tabs nav show active tab

Tags: javascript, html

In the picture I have tabs
with responsive query nav tabs scroll for see other navs
I want show active tab when reload page in responsive mode but now show first of the nav tab

```
 <div class="nav tabs-list" id="trips-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a  id="pills-home-1" data-toggle="pill" href="#home1" role="tab" aria-controls="home1" aria-selected="false">پیمایشی</a>
                    <a  id="pills-home-2" data-toggle="pill" href="#home2" role="tab" aria-controls="home2" aria-selected="false">طبیعت گردی</a>
                    <a  id="pills-home-3" data-toggle="pill" href="#home3" role="tab" aria-controls="home3" aria-selected="false">ماجراجویی</a>
                    <a class="active" id="pills-home-4" data-toggle="pill" href="#home4" role="tab" aria-controls="home4" aria-selected="true">
                        <img src="assets/img/campground.svg">
                        کمپینگ
                    </a>
                    <a class="" id="pills-home-5" data-toggle="pill" href="#home5" role="tab" aria-controls="home5" aria-selected="false">کوهنوردی</a>
                    <a class="" id="pills-home-6" data-toggle="pill" href="#home6" role="tab" aria-controls="home6" aria-selected="false">دوچرخه</a>
                    <a class="" id="pills-home-7" data-toggle="pill" href="#home7" role="tab" aria-controls="home7" aria-selected="false">تور کودک</a>
                </div>
```

[image]

I want show active tab when open the page in mobile like the second picture

[image]

Comment: it is simple can you add code js

Answer (score 0):

To do this, it's simple you have added a javascript code that list all `<a> nav` then add an event earphone to listen to the click event then excute the code here is the code with explanation comments each line of code

```js
// Get all the <a> elements with the "nav" class
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav a');

// Add click event listener to each <a> element
allLinks.forEach((link) =>{
  link.addEventListener('click',()=> {
    // Remove all active class <a>
    allLinks.forEach((navLink)=> {
        navLink.classList.remove('active');
    });
    // Add clacc activ in <a> clicked
    link.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
  
  .nav.tabs-list a.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
     <div class="nav tabs-list" id="trips-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a  id="pills-home-1" data-toggle="pill" href="#home1" role="tab" aria-controls="home1" aria-selected="false">پیمایشی</a>
                    <a  id="pills-home-2" data-toggle="pill" href="#home2" role="tab" aria-controls="home2" aria-selected="false">طبیعت گردی</a>
                    <a  id="pills-home-3" data-toggle="pill" href="#home3" role="tab" aria-controls="home3" aria-selected="false">ماجراجویی</a>
                    <a class="active" id="pills-home-4" data-toggle="pill" href="#home4" role="tab" aria-controls="home4" aria-selected="true">
                        <img src="assets/img/campground.svg">
                        کمپینگ
                    </a>
                    <a class="" id="pills-home-5" data-toggle="pill" href="#home5" role="tab" aria-controls="home5" aria-selected="false">کوهنوردی</a>
                    <a class="" id="pills-home-6" data-toggle="pill" href="#home6" role="tab" aria-controls="home6" aria-selected="false">دوچرخه</a>
                    <a class="" id="pills-home-7" data-toggle="pill" href="#home7" role="tab" aria-controls="home7" aria-selected="false">تور کودک</a>
                </div>
```

I hope that I have helped you and if you are going to any other problem, I am here at your reference

Comment: Thank you very much, but what I want is for this to happen in the responsive version

Comment: I have answered you based on your question